# Creating User Alerts in SharePoint Online Through Csom/ Powershell Csom

Tags: sharepoint, csom

is there any way to create user alerts through csom for sharepoint online?   I am not able to find any msdn references for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not available in Client Object Model for SharePoint Online.

Take a look to this thread:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b59f652e-54d7-449f-bc46-182ae86c0c08/action?threadDisplayName=o365-user-alerts-via-csom